# Hibernate speed, and hard drive temperature

Tags: hard-drive, hibernate, overheating

My computer is taking in the region of 4 minutes or so, to hibernate 4GB of RAM.

Also, resting my hand on the top of it is rather hot to the touch, so I ran CrystalDisk Info and that is reporting a temperature of 49 degrees C.

I It's a Western Digital 5400 rpm drive, I've had it in the laptop since I bought it for most of the 2.75 years I've had it.

Power on Count is 1219
Power on Hours is 3940 hours

Boot up time is quicker than resuming from hibernate, too.

Is there anything I can / should check ?

Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS ? It sounds like a problems with hibernation file/partition...  You can also check the reallocated sectors count on the hard drive. And how much are 2.75 years :) ?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate.33 months.